# RE: Luhn's Check

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to write my code that it reads from the right to left, not left to right

```
 public static int sumofEvenSpot(long number)
{
    int sumEvenSpot = 0;
    String stringLength = Long.toString(number);

    for (int i = 0; i< stringLength.length(); i += 2)
        sumEvenSpot += (getDigit(Character.getNumericValue(stringLength.charAt(i)) * 2));
    return sumEvenSpot;
}
```

Comment: Run the for-loop "backwards" from `stringLength.length()-1` to zero.

Comment: By the way, why do you multiply by 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `for(int i = stringLength.length() - 1; i = 0; i = i - 2)`

(  `for(start, end, increment)` )

OR

You can reverse your string and do a normal for but it takes more code

Answer (score 0):

You can start summing from the rightmost digit, and every iteration divide the number by 100 in order to remove the current digit and the next one (in the odd place) in order to keep summing the following even digit:

```
int sum = 0;    
while(number > 0) {    
    sum += number % 10;
    number /= 100;
}
```

One advantage of doing it this way is that you don't have to convert the long to string and then back to int.